# Why does Java only read the second line of input?

Tags: java

The problem with my code is this: I type my input into the first line in the console but it does not read it until I type anything and enter it into line 2.

For example: I type "Jayden" as a name, push enter, and nothing happens. I then type (insert any letters here) and then it prints "Your name is over 3 letters and starts with the letter J!".
Any ideas?

```
import java.util.*;
public class random {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try (Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            if (number.nextLine().startsWith("J") && number.nextLine().length() > 3 )
            {
                System.out.println("Your name is over 3 letters and starts with the letter J!");
            }

            else if  (number.nextLine().length() < 3)
            {
                System.out.println("Your name is too short!");
            }

            else if (number.nextLine().length() > 10)
            {
                System.out.println("Your name is too long!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time you call `nextLine()` you **consume** the line. You need to save it in a variable, or you will be entering a lot of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that (as Elliot Frisch commented) every time you call nextLine() you consume the line, so  in your initial *if* statement

```
if (number.nextLine().startsWith("J") && // this nextLine reads an input line
    number.nextLine().length() > 3 )     // this nextLine reads a SECOND line
```

You want to read only *one* line, so call nextLine only once and save it in a variable.

Just add this to after the beginning of the try-block (declaring a variable):

```
String numberString = number.nextLine()
```

and then substitute the `number.nextLine()` with the variable in your conditions!

Answer (score 1):

Store your user input into a variable, in my example, I've created a variable called `String userInput = number.nextLine();`

Then carry out your validation on the variable.

Example 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter something : ");
    String userInput = number.nextLine();

    if (userInput.startsWith("J") && userInput.length() > 3) {

        System.out.println("Your name is over 3 letters and starts with the letter J!");

    } else if (userInput.length() < 3) {
        System.out.println("Your name is too short!");

    } else if (userInput.length() > 10) {
        System.out.println("Your name is too long!");


    }

}
```

Comment: Your solution is fine, but when answering the question you ought to explain what's wrong with the OP's code — _why_ it's requiring a second line to be input.

Comment: Also, what if it doesn't start with J, or it's only 3 characters long?

Comment: Agree @Andy, however those conditions are in the OP's question. I might have written an _aside_ about them had I answered, but they don't have to be addressed to answer the question.

Comment: I agree with all comments. How the OP wishes to validate the input is out of scope for this question.